# get all annotated member properties in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to get all member properties' JsonPath in kotlin.
Following is my data class with annotated fields

```kotlin
class Test(
    @Mask val testField: String?,
    val nested: NestedTest,
    val nestedList: List<NestedTest>?,
    val generic: GenericTest<NestedGenericTest>
)

class NestedTest(
    @Mask val test2: String = "",
    val nestedNestedTest: NestedNestedTest = NestedNestedTest()
)

class NestedNestedTest(
    @Mask
    val test3: String = ""
)

class GenericTest<T>(
    val generic: T
)

class NestedGenericTest(
    @Mask
    val nestedGeneric: String
)
```

H'm trying using kotlin-reflection, but I don't care what I use.
how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's start with defining our annotation.

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Mask
```

The important thing here is the retention, which must be runtime.

In my solution I am going to operate on Kotlin properties, so I need to slightly change the Annotation target:

```kotlin
// from
class Clazz(
    @Mask val field: Field
)
// to
class Clazz(
    @property:Mask val field: Field
)
```

What I need to do is to take all object properties and iterate over them (to find all marked fields).

At first lest define some types I am not going to get deeper. In my case, it's just a list of primitives and String:

```kotlin
val simpleTypes = setOf(
    // define types you would like to stop iterating (like "basic types")
    Byte::class,
    Boolean::class,
    Short::class,
    Integer::class,
    Long::class,
    Float::class,
    Double::class,
    Char::class,
    String::class,
)
```

So, in my function, I am going to return a property definition with its value:

```kotlin
typealias KPropertyWithValue = Pair<KProperty1<out Any, *>, Any?>
```

To finally get my functions:

```kotlin
fun getMaskedFromObject(v: Any?): List<KPropertyWithValue> {
    // early returns - support for some special types, like Collection, Arrays etc.
    when {
        v == null -> return emptyList()
        v is Collection<*> -> return v.flatMap { getMaskedFromObject(it) }
        v is Array<*> -> return v.flatMap { getMaskedFromObject(it) }
        // support for other types (Streams, custom collections etc.)
        v::class in simpleTypes -> return emptyList()
    }

    v!! // just a mark the v is not null at this point - kotlin compiler is not handling the first when/return properly

    val properties = v::class.memberProperties
    val annotated = properties.filter { it.annotations.any { ann -> ann is Mask } }
    val propertyValues = properties.map { it.getter.call(v) }

    val annotatedWithValue = annotated.map {
        val value = it.getter.call(v)
        Pair(it, value)
    }

    return annotatedWithValue + propertyValues.flatMap { getMaskedFromObject(it) }
}
```

So, with a code like:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val test = Test(
        testField = "root_testField",
        nested = NestedTest(
            test2 = "nested_test2",
            nestedNestedTest = NestedNestedTest(
                test3 = "nested_test3"
            )
        ),
        nestedList = listOf(
            NestedTest(
                test2 = "list_test2",
                nestedNestedTest = NestedNestedTest(
                    test3 = "list_test3"
                )
            )
        ),
        generic = GenericTest(
            generic = NestedGenericTest(
                nestedGeneric = "generic_nested"
            )
        )
    )

    val result = getMaskedFromObject(test)
    result.forEach { 
        println(it)
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.Test.testField: kotlin.String?, root_testField)
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.NestedGenericTest.nestedGeneric: kotlin.String, generic_nested)
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.NestedTest.test2: kotlin.String, nested_test2)
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.NestedNestedTest.test3: kotlin.String, nested_test3)
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.NestedTest.test2: kotlin.String, list_test2)
(val com.example.springsandbox.utils.NestedNestedTest.test3: kotlin.String, list_test3)
```

Please notice a few things:

- there are a few types that would require additional coding (Arrays, maps, custom collections, Streams etc.)
- we cannot determine if a value comes from the object (by nesting) or the collection, but it's possible to create such a "path" while processing the object
- I am operating on Kotlin Properties, there will be a few differences if you would like to operate on Java fields